# Building gcc 4.5.2 on snow leopard fails linking with unsupported file format

Tags: macos, gcc

I'm working on OS X 10.6.6 to build a gcc cross-compiler and gnu java for an embedded system.  gcc native and cross need to be the same version, so I want to get everything up to the latest gcc version.  After building gmp, mpfr, mpc, and binutils with no problem, building native gcc is failing with what I think is the first link step.  The specific step that fails is:

```
fixincludes$ gcc -g -O2  -o fixincl fixincl.o fixtests.o fixfixes.o server.o procopen.o fixlib.o fixopts.o ../libiberty/libiberty.a
ld: warning: in ../libiberty/libiberty.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

Lots of undefined symbol errors follow this warning.  libiberty.a and the .o files appear to be the same architecture:

```
fixincludes$ lipo -info ../libiberty/libiberty.a input file ../libiberty/libiberty.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: ../libiberty/libiberty.a is architecture: x86_64
fixincludes$ lipo -info *.o
Non-fat file: fixfixes.o is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: fixincl.o is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: fixlib.o is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: fixopts.o is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: fixtests.o is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: procopen.o is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: server.o is architecture: x86_64
```

I suspect this has to do with 32-bit vs 64-bit, but I don't know what else to check and can't find a specific solution anywhere.  Can anyone tell me what's going on here or just nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Russ.  I'm looking to get gcc 4.5.2 functional on my Mac OS X 10.6.6 dev box as well, as I'd like to experiment with gcc's C++0x support.  Have you had any success since this post ?

Comment: Hi Scott.  I've done nothing further on OS X.  I still have hope for stackoverflow.